# Remove last char from result of a match regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract a part of html in a jmeter test.

I need to extract just a part from a `<script src=""` tag.

- full script src:
  `<script src="/Paginas/Inicializacao/AguardarAcao.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d1.0.11119.38311%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3apt-BR%3adf9c6e46-ef8c-4a3d-89af-f80adf22e9c2%3a865923e8%3a411fea1c%3ae7c87f07%3a91bd373d%3a1d58b08c%3a8e72a662%3aacd642d2%3a596d588c%3a77c58d20%3a14b56adc%3a269a19ae" type="text/javascript"></script>`
- and I need just:
  `%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d1.0.11119.38311%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3apt-BR%3adf9c6e46-ef8c-4a3d-89af-f80adf22e9c2%3a865923e8%3a411fea1c%3ae7c87f07%3a91bd373d%3a1d58b08c%3a8e72a662%3aacd642d2%3a596d588c%3a77c58d20%3a14b56adc%3a269a19ae`

Right now I created this regex:

```
%3b.*"
```

that matches:

```
%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d1.0.11119.38311%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3apt-BR%3adf9c6e46-ef8c-4a3d-89af-f80adf22e9c2%3a865923e8%3a411fea1c%3ae7c87f07%3a91bd373d%3a1d58b08c%3a8e72a662%3aacd642d2%3a596d588c%3a77c58d20%3a14b56adc%3a269a19ae"
```

But I don't want the last two chars (one white space) and the `"`.
How to remove this last two chars?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I think it is important to reiterate that parsing with regex is a terrible idea that may [summon cthulu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19148934)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use regular expression pattern

```
%[^"]+
```

Comment: How would you do it if you really want to remove the last char from any selection?

Comment: @J.Doe - That depends on what regex language/engine you need/want to use. If your regex engine supports a positive lookahead, then try to use a pattern `^.*(?=.$)` - see https://regexr.com/4aras

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a positive look-ahead could help, something like:

```
%3b.*(?="\s)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
^(.*).{1}
```

works really well

the ^ denotes the start of the line, the (.*) captures any number of characters and the .{1} removes the last character from the string

for example:

Input: 100.00%

Output 100.00

Comment: Are we sure that .{1} removes the last character?  Seems to do the opposite, include the NEXT character

Comment: I think they meant for the user to return $1 as delimited by the parentheses, this would effectively exclude the .{1}, but is not the best solution